# GCD between an irreducible polynomial of degree $n$ in $\mathbb{F}_p[x]$ and $x^{p^n} - x$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, field-theory, finite-fields, irreducible-polynomials

I was viewing the proof of Proposition 1.1 in some notes I found on factoring polynomials in $\mathbb{F}_p[x]$ at https://wstein.org/129-05/section/m129-section-factoring-poly-mod-p/factoring_poly_mod_p.pdf. Specifically, I'm only worried about the second sentence in the first paragraph of the proof.

Basically, if I have an irreducible polynomial $f$ of degree $n$ in $\mathbb{F}_p[x]$, the author argues that $(f(x), x^{p^n} - x) \neq 1$ in $\mathbb{F}_{p^n}[x]$. This part is completely fine for me.

But, the author then makes the claim that this implies that $(f(x), x^{p^n}-x) \neq 1$ in $\mathbb{F}_p[x]$. I'm struggling with seeing why this implication follows. Is there a fairly trivial reason for this that I'm not seeing ? Or is there more high-powered machinery involved ?

Thanks!

Comment: You calculate the gcd of two polynomials using Euclid's algorithm. If both polynomials have their coefficients in a field $K$, then the algorithm never leaves $K[x]$, so the gcd is also in $K[x]$. Similarly, the gcd of two polynomials with coefficients in $\Bbb{Q}$ is in $\Bbb{Q}[x]$ even thoug the polynomials themselves may have more factors over $\Bbb{R}$ or some other field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that as $f$ is irreducible, $L=\mathbb{F}_p[x]/f(x)\mathbb{F}_p[x]$ is a field with $p^n$ elements. So for every nonzero element $\alpha(x) \in L$, the equation $\alpha^{p^n-1}(x) \equiv 1$ mod $f(x)$ holds. [As in every field $K$ with $q^n$ elements the equation $a^{q^n-1} = 1$ holds for each $a \in K^{\times}$.] This implies that for every $\alpha(x) \in L$ [including trivially $\alpha=0$], the resulting $\alpha^{p^n}(x)-\alpha(x)$ is 0 in $L$.

This implies that for every $\alpha(x) \in \mathbb{F}_p[x]$ [including trivially $\alpha=0$], the resulting $\alpha^{p^n}(x)-\alpha(x)$ is a multiple of $f(x)$ in $\mathbb{F}_p[x]$ i.e., divide $\alpha^{p^n}(x)-\alpha(x)$ by $f(x)$ in $\mathbb{F}_p[x]$ the remainder will be 0. This implies that for every $\alpha(x) \in \mathbb{F}_p[x]$ there is a $g_{\alpha}(x) \in \mathbb{F}_p[x]$ such that $\alpha^{p^n}(x)-\alpha(x) = g_{\alpha}(x)f(x)$.

Taking $\alpha(x) = x$ one concludes $x^{p^n}-x$ is a multiple of $f(x)$ in $\mathbb{F}_p[x]$. Which gives you your desired result.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I have two questions. One, did you mean to write $L = \mathbb{F}_p[x]/f(x)\mathbb{F}_p[x]$, or did you mean to write $L = \mathbb{F}_p[x]/(f)$ ? Also, where have we used the assumption here that $(f(x), x^{p^n}-x) \neq 1$ in $\mathbb{F}_{p^n}[x]$ ? I appreciate your time, sir.

Comment: Hi @michiganbiker898  1. I meant $L$ is the field of polynomials in $\mathbb{F}_p[x]$ mod $f$. 2. I used the fact that $f$ is an irreducible polynomial in $\mathbb{F}_p[x]$ of degree $n$ to prove directly that indeed $f|(x^{p^n}-x)$

Comment: Aah, I see. So the assumption wasn't used. Thanks for your help and awesome work. I appreciate your time. (=

Comment: Glad I could help! I do believe that it is in general true though that if $f,g \in \mathbb{F}_K[x]$; $K$ a field do not share a common factor in $\mathbb{F}_K[x]$, then $f$ and $g$ do not share a common factor in $\mathbb{F}_L[x]$, for any other field $L$ containing $K$. This is a sketch of the proof for $f$ irreducible in $\mathbb{F}_k[x]$: Let $a$ be a common root of $f$ and $g$. Then $f$ is the lowest-degree polynomial in $\mathbb{F}_k[x]$ having $a$ as a root...

Comment: But let $r$ be the remainder of dividing $f$ into $g$. Then $r \in \mathbb{F}_K[x]$ and $r(a) = 0$ and deg$(r) < $deg$(f)$, which is a contradiction.